# Error defining a list with a templated class

Tags: generics, kotlin

I have the following:

```
data class GenericItem<T> (val id: Int, val data: T)
```

I am trying to define a generic list as follows:

```
val rows: List<GenericItem<T>>
```

but I get an error:

> one type argument expected for class GenericItem

What am I doing wrong here and how can I fix it?

Comment: Where is T coming from? For that code to work, it has to be inside something generic, like a function or a class. Please post the surrounding code

Comment: @gpunto: `T` is something I defined. It is not a concrete class

Comment: I know, but it must be defined somewhere else in the outer scope for that line to compile. Like a class or a function having T as a generic parameter.

Answer (score 0):

When you're using the `GenericItem` inside of

```
List<GenericItem<T>>
```

you can't refer to the type that's contained in `GenericItem` as `T` because at this point it assumes you're using it with a real type, not with a generic.

The solution would be to pass in the value that is now actually contained in your `GenericItem` ie

```
List<GenericItem<Int>>
List<GenericItem<String>>
```

Or whatever type you please

If you want to limit the types that you are allowed to define on the generic `T` you can change your definition to define it like so

```
GenericItem<T: YourCustomType>
```

And make it so that you can only pass in a generic that is, or whose parent is `YourCustomType`

Comment: I see that if I use `<*>` the compilation works. Is that correct?

Comment: You can also use `<*>` yes, but it really depends on what you want the functionality to be, when you pass in `*` you are saying you want to be able to pass in any type into that list, but you can only pass in that type. If you used something like `Any` you can pass in multiple types